# Page unload event in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to call a write a Page_Unload event in code behind similar to Page_Load event? I wanted to call a method on Page Unload. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 39):

With `AutoEventWireup` which is turned on by default on a page you can just add methods prepended with **Page_***event* and have ASP.NET connect to the events for you.

In the case of Unload the method signature is:

```
protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

For details see the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178492.aspx).

Answer (score 31):

Refer to the [ASP.NET page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) to help find the right event to override. It really depends what you want to do. But yes, there is an unload event.

```
    protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnUnload(e);

        // your code
    }
```

But just remember (from the above link): *During the unload stage, the page and its controls have been rendered, so you cannot make further changes to the response stream. If you attempt to call a method such as the Response.Write method, the page will throw an exception.*

Answer (score 9):

There is an event `Page.Unload`. At that moment page is already rendered in HTML and HTML can't be modified. Still, all page objects are available.