# C# if page is closed and page close events

Tags: c#, web-applications

I am writing a Web Forms Application in .Net Framework 4.5. In an ASP page, is there any way to check and do some action before closing browser page. For example, sign out or call a function if user clicked "X (close)" button of tab or browser window. Is there any method to handle this exit? (I also prefer having close reason. user closed or error closed etc.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117870/page-unload-event-in-asp-net

Comment: @AhmedMasud `Control.Unload` isn't triggered when you close a browser window. So not a dupe.
However this question has the answer he's looking for http://stackoverflow.com/q/16584663/1193596

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Unload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.unload.aspx) event, but if you are to implement **something before the page is closed**, you should do this on the client side since you cannot make further changes to the response stream  when `Unload` is called. Please refer [Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for details.

[Jquery Unload](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) is a good choice for that type of controls.