# Execute code when website is closed

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a method to run code every time the user closes out of an ASP.NET webpage? I am pretty new to ASP and don't know very much about HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I usually creat an unload function, and add a `onbeforeunload` to the parent body of where you'd like the function run, like so

```
<body onbeforeunload="closingFunction()">

function closingFunction(){
    //DO STUFF
}
```

There may be some more relevant information for you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117870/page-unload-event-in-asp-net)